# How to override background style back to original?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have the following situation :

```
.table_green {
background: #B4E391;
}
.data_table tbody tr:hover {
background-color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
}
.unclickable_table tbody tr:hover {
background-color: inherit;
cursor: default;
}
```

Now the `tr` originaly is green color, and i want when a table has `class='data_table unclickable_table'` set, that on hover on a `tr` that has `table_green` class, the `background-color` property won't change and stay green, but `inherit` doesn't seem to work

Example html :

```
<table class='data_table unclickable_table'>
<tbody>
<tr class='table_green'>
 <td>Untill it goes Click!</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Or this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nyDNc/1/

Any help?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want the hover to work on a row that has `table_green`?

Comment: I don't really understand your question aswell

Comment: @crush No on tables that has `unclicktable_table`, the background-color turns to grey instead of staying green

Comment: When does it turn to grey? It's green, then white on hover in your fiddle.

Comment: @crush I meant to turns to white, sorry.

Comment: What behavior do you want?

Comment: @crush I want to disable the change of background, so in this case it will turn to green, but this is a generic class so i want it to always return to the background color set by it's other classes, so in case it has a class which sets the background to red, it'll become red.

Comment: Your `tr:hover` is getting both styles. First it attaches white background and then inherits that attached white background.

Comment: @TomMaitland See my above comment.

Comment: so do a `.unclickable_table .table_green:hover { background: #B4E391; }` rule...

Comment: @crush Yeah but that will make me write this rules for each of the classes available, can't i just disable it? i HAVE to override it with a specific background color?

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what exactly you want.

Comment: All the question is asking is essentially a way to disable a hover effect within that structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution, hopefully one that will work within your structure cause it depends on how you're styling your table elements.

`inherit` won't work because it is inheriting from the table which has a background of none. Instead you can have the `tr` set and change the colour of the `td` on hover, so that it has a context to inherit from.

See the working example [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tommaitland/r5AEh/).

The CSS is:

```
.table_green {
  background: #B4E391;
}
.data_table tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.unclickable_table.data_table tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: inherit;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it will affect the entire table, and this table has rows with `table_red` class, which sets the background to red.

Comment: The background colour is still inherited from the row, so those rows with table_red should still stay red?

Comment: Updated fiddle with two different rows with those classes http://jsfiddle.net/tommaitland/r5AEh/1/

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work because of the order of appearnce of the classes?

Comment: Its inheriting background from the `<tbody>` not the `<table>`

Comment: No the issue was just that `.unclickable_table tbody tr:hover { background-color: inherit; }` was inheriting from the next element down, in this case the `<tbody>`. `inherit` will take styles from the parent not from it's own element. As `tbody` had no background that's what it was reverting to.

Comment: Yeah I know. I didn't see your comment until I posted my comment and reloaded the page.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add a second class in order to override the effect the first class has. Why don't you just remove the 'data_table' classes on the rows you don't want the effect on.

Comment: Because `data_table` as alot of styling I DO want. and `data_table` is a table level class.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understand You very well, but

```
DEMO IS HERE:
http://jsfiddle.net/nyDNc/1/
```